# Can´t install Hudson Plugin after update Hudson

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I got a problem with Hudson Plugins installation and I can´t find a solution.

Environment:
Server: Tomcat 6.0.16
System: Ubuntu 10.4
Hudson: Hudson 2.2
Java Version: JDK 1.7.0_03

My problem:
I updated Hudson from version 2.1 to 2.2. all builds running as before.
But the Plugins that I installed on my old Hudson version doesn’t appear in the Hudson Plugin Manager under "installed". When I install the old Plugins (FindBugs,PMD,...) in Hudson again, the installation process runs successfully but after restart Hudson the Plugins doesn’t appear neither under "installed". So I can’t install any Hudson Plugin.

Have someone an idea how I can find out where the problem is?

Thx for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem!

I think the problem were the old plugin artifacts that still were in the var/local/hudson/plugin directory.

**The instructions to solve my problem:**

- Stop and undeploy Hudson on the Tomcat
- Delete all Hudson Plugins in the var/local/Hudson/plugin directory
- Deploy Hudson on the Tomcat (All required Hudson Plugins were installed from Hudson)

  Now the installation of new Hudson Plugins is possible again. ;)